# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - UIWebView in RxSwift.framework

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, deprecated, rx-swift

I have updated my app replacing UIWebView with WKWebView.
It includes a framework that requires *RXSwift* framework version 4.5.0, that uses UIWebView (this have been fixed in a newer version).

I have updated my app and I'm not receiving the warning about UIWebView usage, even if RxSwift is using them, why is that?

is it safe to assume that the app won't be rejected after December 2020?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe to assume the app won't be rejected after December 2020, but it is safe to assume that any app submitted and accepted before December 2020 will remain in the app store. It is fine to submit apps which use the RxSwift framework even though it uses the deprecated UIWebView for the time being.

RxSwift 5.1.0 has already removed UIWebView according to this changelog.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/releases/tag/5.1.0

I would look into whatever framework you are using that depends on RxSwift 4.5.0 and inquire when they are looking to upgrade to 5.1.0.

Comment: Is It possibile that Xcode is stripping UIWebView's symbols in RxSwift because they are actually unused?